# getElementByID from link function for data bound id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to access an element in a directive template by id from the Link function.
However, the element id is data bound and doesn't appear to be available at the time the link function runs.

I have demonstrated the issue in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vmgT3CaUbkaPNn6gDHJh

```
link: function (scope) {
    var textbox = angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.id));

          textbox.bind('blur', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.value = textbox.val();
            });
          });
```

If I hard code the id of the element this works ok - but as demonstrated in this fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/5qML3rGBwiCC7fc8eKVf because I am attaching an event listener by id, if I reuse the hard coded id I do not get the isolation to the instance of the directive that I need.

```
link: function (scope) {
          var textbox = angular.element(document.getElementById('id'));

          textbox.bind('blur', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.value = textbox.val();
            });
          });
        }
```

Is there a function other than link that I can run this code in when the databound id will be available?  Or am I just trying to do this entirely in the wrong way?

Comment: You seem to be binding to the textboxes themselves, so you could just use `ng-blur`.  `ng-model` would also work but that will change when a key is pressed rather than just on blur.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Explosion Pills; you are correct; you can do this much easier by using the capabilities already in Angular.

I've forked the Plunker with the updated code: http://plnkr.co/edit/e0jD6RnwXbRQOc9NfdiS

```
link: function (scope) {
          scope.blur = function(){
            console.log(scope.value);
          }
        }
```

and the template:

```
<div>
<label for="{{::id}}">{{::label}}</label>
<input class="form-control" id="{{::id}}" type="{{::type}}" placeholder=" {{::placeholder}}" ng-model="value" ng-blur="blur()">
<div>{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

I still have the one time binding of the ID in the template as it is used by the label; but the directive itself is built up using just ng functions.